# ansible-lint during pre-commit in CI/CD

Tags: git, ansible, cicd, pre-commit.com, ansible-lint

Locally run `ansible-lint` `pre-commit` behaves differently than run during CI/CD.

I use following

```yaml
---
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint
    rev: v24.2.1
    hooks:
      - id: ansible-lint
```

That is because `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` is available locally which also configures e.g. collection path where private collections are installed.

During the `ansible-lint` run a `requirements.yml` is picked up such that dependencies would be installed. Since the collections are private, I would need to hardcode an access token which seems wrong to me. I tried using

```yaml
---
collections:
  - name: "git+https://<token name>:${token}@<private git repo"
    type: git
    version: "*"
```

and setting `export token=<token with access>` but this did not work.

I also tried to use a `.ansible-lint` config with

```yaml
---
mock_modules:
  - <namespace>.<name>.<role>
```

or

```yaml
mock_roles:
  - <namespace>.<name>.<role>
```

but not if it helped.

Related questions:

- How do I make `ansible-lint` `pre-commit` behave the same locally and during CI/CD?
- How to ignore locally available config?
- How to specify authentication in `requirements.yml`, e.g. via an environment variable?

Comment: seems to me you have the answer you just don't like it.  it sounds like ansible lint isn't really a linter since it basically needs access to all of your live credentials and playbooks rather than just your source

Comment: I think there is a few issues in this approach. You should not be linting your dependencies, Since they are in their own private collection they should be linted in that projects CI flow. You should only lint your own code as @anthonysottile mentioned. However to address your question on credentials in the requirements file. Your correct, they dont belong there. Write the plain url, and then in your pipeline you can do something like this before you install the requirements. `git config --global url."https://oauth2:${CISERVER_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}".insteadOf ${CI_SERVER_URL}`

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf

Comment: @ChrisDoyle `ansible-lint` does not lint the dependencies but since it runs `ansible-playbook` under the hood it needs all the dependencies to be resolved.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle To be clear, It does not try to lint the code in the dependencies, it rather detects that my code has dependencies and checks if they are available. I try to mock the dependencies but for some reason the config file is not picked up.